# transactions for future use

Tags: transactions

If bitcoins can be stolen via hacking, what's there to stop these already occurring events and bitcoins from falling right back into the hands of power. I mean bitcoins are capable of being untraceable. So who's to say that its NOT already being utilized as the new, maybe even world, currency for control?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too philosophical, and seems to be getting at some sort of conspiracy theory.

Comment: Please ask more concrete question.

Comment: @Jestin agreed. Too speculative and is remotely related to the technicalities of Bitcoin itself.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way: Bitcoins can get stolen by people with poor private key control being "hacked". But when those people have their Bitcoins stolen, what do they do? They complain about it online, and so other people hear about it.

Then those people who hear about it say to themselves: "well my private key control is pretty bad too, I can easily get hacked!" Then some of them will at least learn to protect themselves, maybe by using a hardware wallet such as Trezor or Ledger.

Those that don't improve their practices will either eventually have their funds stolen, or they will see more examples and their behavior will self-correct.

Also if there was a sudden increase in thefts there would be a LOT of media coverage about it, and even more people would learn about how to protect themselves through these good private key practices.

Because of this, the amount of Bitcoin that is stolen annually will tend towards some small percentage. Of course, if Bitcoin did look like it was going to be *the* global currency you can imagine that the already-rich-capitalists would just buy a whole lot of Bitcoin, so it wouldn't make that much of a difference to their lives and position.